# Another ANONYMOUS LOGIN Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two servers/instances, both MSSQL 2012. I have a linked server set up on SERVER1 "using the login's current security context" (@useself='TRUE') and RPC set to TRUE. SERVER1 is using domain account MYDOMAIN\SQL$ACCT for its service account.

Here is what happens when I run the following at a command prompt:

```
C:\> sqlcmd -S Server1 -E -d MYDB -Q "SELECT * FROM SERVER2.MyRemoteDB.dbo.Contacts;"
Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Server SERVER2, Line 1
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
```

Here is my setup for SPN on SERVER1:

```
C:\> setspn -L MYDOMAIN\SQL$ACCT
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=SQL$ACCT,OU=Users,OU=SQL Admin,OU=Administrative Control,DC=YY,DC=ZZZ:
    MSSQLSvc/Server1.yy.zzz:1433
    MSSQLSvc/Server1.yy.zzz

C:\> setspn -L Server1
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=SERVER1,OU=Production,OU=Servers,DC=YY,DC=ZZZ:
    CmRcService/SERVER1.yy.zzz
    CmRcService/SERVER1
    WSMAN/SERVER1
    WSMAN/SERVER1.yy.zzz
    TERMSRV/SERVER1.YY.ZZZ
    TERMSRV/SERVER1
    RestrictedKrbHost/SERVER1
    HOST/SERVER1
    RestrictedKrbHost/SERVER1.YY.ZZZ
    HOST/SERVER1.YY.ZZZ
```

Domain account MYDOMAIN\SQL$ACCT is set up for **Trust this user for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)**. SERVER1 is set up for **Trust this user for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)**.

I am sysadmin in both instances, so no permission issues within SQL Server.

what am I missing?

Comment: I'm no expert in the AD stuff, but did you verify that your connection is using Kerberos (and not the old NTLM)? Sys.dm_exec_connections, methinks it is.

Comment: Well apparently not:
`auth_scheme
----------------------------------------
NTLM`

Comment: Try connecting with FQDN `sqlcmd -S Server1.yy.zzz . . .`

Comment: Interesting. FQDN appears to work. What gives?

Comment: looks like the only SPNs you have set are FQDN ones.